# How to read a untidy csv file in java and create a corresponding ArrayList of an object?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I want to read this [csvFile](https://sites.google.com/a/iemcal.com/cs504d-oop/project/requirements-2016/2016.spicejet.csv) into an array of *Flight* class objects in which each index will refer to an object containing a record from the [csvFile](https://sites.google.com/a/iemcal.com/cs504d-oop/project/requirements-2016/2016.spicejet.csv).

Here is a blueprint of *Flight* class. Its not complete so I am only providing the data memebers.

```
public class Flight {
  private String flightID;
  private String source;
  private String destination;
  private <some clas to handle time > dep;
  private <some clas to handle time> arr;
  private String[] daysOfWeek;
  private <some clas to handle date> efff;
  private <some clas to handle date> efft;
  private <some clas to handle dates> exc;
```

}

I want to implement a function something like :

```
public class DataManager {



public List<Flight> readSpiceJet() {
    return new ArrayList<Flight>(); 
}
```

}

Feel free to modify this and please help me. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes we will feel free.. but can you show us your current implementation of this.. the ones you have tried and havent worked?

Comment: I could not implement this thing I tried cleaning the csv data using openCSV library but that didn't helped me in achieving my goal to create an Array of objects. All it returned was Strings not objects.

Comment: Might be a good idea to post your code that you mentioned didn't help you. Someone may be able to spot where you went wrong. Much better than asking someone to give you a solution from scratch.

Comment: please post the code that did not work for you

Comment: `CSVReader spicejetreader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data/2016.spicejet.csv"),'|','\'',4);`  `String[] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = spicejetreader.readNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println(nextLine[2]);
     }`        this reurns a string which i am unable to parse into a object  @Blip @Adrian

Comment: Edit your question and post the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try OpenCSV Framework.

Have a look at this example:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategy;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;

public class ParseCSVtoJavaBean 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CSVReader csvReader = null;

        try
        {
            /**
             * Reading the CSV File
             * Delimiter is comma
             * Default Quote character is double quote
             * Start reading from line 1
             */
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Employee.csv"),',','"',1);
            //mapping of columns with their positions
            ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy = 
                    new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
            //Set mappingStrategy type to Employee Type
            mappingStrategy.setType(Employee.class);
            //Fields in Employee Bean
            String[] columns = new String[]{"empId","firstName","lastName","salary"};
            //Setting the colums for mappingStrategy
            mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
            //create instance for CsvToBean class
            CsvToBean ctb = new CsvToBean();
            //parsing csvReader(Employee.csv) with mappingStrategy  
            List empList = ctb.parse(mappingStrategy,csvReader);
            //Print the Employee Details
            for(Employee emp : empList)
            {
                System.out.println(emp.getEmpId()+"   "+emp.getFirstName()+"   "
                        +emp.getLastName()+"   "+emp.getSalary());

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                //closing the reader
                csvReader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

To parse dates:

```
String dateString;
Date date;

public void setDateString(String dateString) {
 // This method can parse the dateString and set date object as well
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
     //parse here
}
```

Comment: can you also suggest how to parse the date and time parts of the records while reading into the date time fileds.

Comment: You might want to create a dateString object in your class and have its setter parse the date as per your requirement.

Comment: please post the well indented code this code is very confusing. Also it can be because i am new into java @arnabkaycee